# Do sass/scss files compile to render the final css file on production on each user page load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, less

I am creating a ruby on Rails app with the usual tools (rails pipeline and rails sass (gem 'sass-rails') and deploy to Heroku.

I am a newbie and what I fail to understand with scss/sass is:

- when I deploy on heroku, do only .css files go the production servers or does each time a user load the homepage, herokus servers need to convert my scss files and the $ variables to serve the "final" css file to the client ?

I can cope with the larger compile time while in dev mode not in production (I'd rather avoid it). At least I need to know if even in production, the css given as example below, will need to go and fetch the scss files

Exemple:

```
.brand {
    @include vertical-align(absolute);
    color: $brandColor;
    right: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In production the assets are precompiled, generating 2 minified files, one for the javascript and one for the css.
In development they are precompiled on each request, but you can simulate the minified one version by changing some options in your `development.rb` file.

Comment: cool thanks, as long as it's only available as a final css file in production, I am reassured. Seems like a basic information about sass but I failed to find a clear answer on the web

Comment: @Mathieu You can read more about it here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production

Answer (score 1):

Rails will use an assets pipeline in your application. Using the files application.css and application.js in your app/assets folder, it will go through the files 'required', and compile them to a single file.

It will process them from Coffee -> JS and SCSS/LESS -> CSS if these Gems are part of your hierarchy.

You can use the following to check the precompilation:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile
```